# Try to insert empty value to sql and I got error “Input string was not in a correct format.”

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms c#.

[image]

I am trying to update the table (PizzaTable) with new values from GataGridView (the 4 columns in sql table are type of money). I want to insert empty value I can insert empty value of DGV cell ( from any column) into sql table BUT not column "Size7" .

the problem is with Size7 column: when I insert empty value in "Size7" column (in DGV) and I click update button it show this error : “Input string was not in a correct format.” but other empty values from other columns can be inserted and updated fine. Why not column Size7?

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Anyone has any idea? Thank you

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  /////######## UPDATE 
    {



         RowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
         MyConnection.Open();

        MyCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE PizzaTable SET  Size7 = @Size7, Size9= @Size9, Size12 =  @Size12, Size14 = @Size14 WHERE PizzaID = @PizzaID";

        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PizzaID", SqlDbType.Int); // DECLARE COMMAND PARAMETERS;
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Size7", SqlDbType.Money);
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Size9", SqlDbType.Money);
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Size12", SqlDbType.Money);
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Size14", SqlDbType.Money);



        for (i = 0; i <= RowIndex; i++)

        {


            MyCommand.Parameters["@PizzaID"].Value = i + 1;

            MyCommand.Parameters["@Size7"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

            MyCommand.Parameters["@Size9"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);


            MyCommand.Parameters["@Size12"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

            MyCommand.Parameters["@Size14"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);

   MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  


        }
```

Comment: You should validate you input.

Comment: Just so you know hard-coding the pizza sizes into the columns is not the best Idea.

Comment: Check what's in `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value` with the debugger. And make sure you are accessing the right cells - indexes `2,3,5,6` look strange for consecutive columns.